# Is the console in Chrome Dev Tools secure?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-devtools

I was investigating why my DirectTV Now service wasn't working in the Chrome Dev Tools to nerd around when I couldn't log in.

I saw that when I try to log in, it logs my password and username.

So I began wondering - is there any way an unsavory Chrome extension or other loaded Javascript files could access things that have been logged to the console?

I've often dumped sensitive items into the log in development, but never in production.

Hoped someone better informed than I am could help me understand if this is secure or not.

Comment: Extension can override console.log, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its in the console, its originating from a console.log() call.  Since console.log() is dumping out to the console log window the contents of some variable or state somewhere in the page, then a plugin can also read the same variables in the running page.